# ViewStack selected seems to work every other time

Tags: randori

It seems like the viewstack tied with a list is failing. I'm getting a TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'provideDecoratedElement' every other time. Is this just me or have others seen it?

```
override protected function onRegister():void
{
    var menuItems:Array = [];
    menuItems.push( new MenuItem("Search","views/search.html") );
    menuItems.push( new MenuItem("Box Office","views/boxoffice.html") );
    ...

    menu.menuItemSelected.add( menuItemSelected );
    menu.data = menuItems;

    menuItemSelected(menuItems[0]);
}

private function menuItemSelected(menuData:MenuItem):void{
    viewStack.popView();
    var promise:Promise = viewStack.pushView(menuData.url);

    promise.then(function(result:AbstractMediator):void{
        Window.console.log(menuData.url);
    }, function(fault:Object):void{
        Window.console.log(fault.toString());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the views you are loading have mediators, make sure those mediators either extends from AbstractMediator or implement the interface. provideDecoratedElement is used to hand a Behavior or Mediator a reference to the element which it decorates.

If its not there, you are loading a class that's not a mediator or a behavior as a mediator or behavior.

Comment: You may want to file a bug here: https://github.com/RandoriAS/randori-sdk that this could use a better error message.